# Assembly manifest error

Tags: .net, windows, assemblies

I am trying to deploy a dll to the assembly folder.C:\Windows\Assembly When i drop this DLL it gives me the following error messsage :

the module 'foo.dll' was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

what could be the possible problem as this is the only assembly that is throwing this error whereas all the remaining assemblies get deployed without any hassle.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you build/compile foo.dll yourself, or is it something you downloaded or received from a vendor?

Answer (score 0):

Use mt.exe from the Windows SDK to compare the manifests of the problem DLL with those of the working ones.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375649(VS.85).aspx